# How to access function from another class?

Tags: c++, function, class, methods

Stupid question probably, but I couldn't find the answer (even here).

I have split all my classes in separate files (cpp+h). I have methods like `getValue()` and `setValue()`. I have class called Player (this is basically the database with whole number of variables). I created an object called player `(Player *player = new Player;)`. Now I need to access THIS object from any other class (that separated in another file). The problem is that I cannot even access `getValue() / setValue()` methods.

What I need is something like in Delphi `From1.player.item[0]=3` access from form 2, where the player is recorded.

UPD:

Here's my code:

Player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "gameform.h"

Player::Player()
{
}

void Player::check(){
    //I should be able to check if player dead or not from my Battle class
}
```

player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    void check();
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

Battle.cpp

```
#include "battle.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "game.h"

Battle::Battle()
{
}

void Battle::hit(){
//if I hit I should check am I dead yet
    player.check();
}
```

That's how Player declared in Game class (now):

```
Player *player = new Player;
```

Outside of any functions, just in class.

Where player is object, created in Game class. All things are public.

*I've tried even creating object in main.cpp (both in and out of main() function), and nothing working, weird =/

This is github "temp" branch, compiling and working. But how to access player? :)

https://github.com/ewancoder/game/tree/temp

UPD: Another stupid question: If I want that in my class 1 function is responsible for opening file and another - for editing and closing file, how can I do that if one cannot read vars from another?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Post your `Player` declaration. It seems your methods are all private. Access `this` is strange. What is your intent?

Comment: It's `player.check()`, not `player.check`. It's a function taking no parameters, that's indicated by `()`.

Comment: Is `player` declared within the `Battle` class? could you post your class declaration for `Battle`?

Comment: player declared within a Game class (it's included in Battle), and Battle should be able to access Game. battle.h looks just like player.h, only with it's own names.

Comment: How are you including `Game` within `Battle`? like this: `class Battle: public Game` or just creating a `Game` object within `Battle`?

Comment: It's included, but this doesn't work. game.--- see all game functions, but doesn't see player. Just creating object :)

Comment: Please post your `Game` and `Battle` classes

Comment: I can't post it right now cause it's total mess, and player even not in Game and everything wrapped around like hell

Comment: Here https://github.com/ewancoder/game/tree/temp

Comment: Declaring variables at the global scope is almost never a good idea, just saying

Comment: The thing is I know that all of this is not a good idea, and I truly want to make this right. BUT how can I do this if I cannot do this even when everything global and public?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want, but if you have a class like this:

**a.hpp**

```
Class A {
    public:
       void foo();
};
```

**a.cpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"
void A::foo() {}
```

You can use it like this:

**b.hpp**

```
#include "a.hpp"
class B {
   public:
      void stuff(A& a);
};
```

**b.cpp**

```
#include "b.hpp"
void B::stuff(A& a) { a.stuff(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the other object the reference of the first. Either direct in the constructor or later via a method.

Or alternativly you could store player in a global variable and access it via the global variable.

The problem is that the methods are bound to the specific instance of the object - and so you need that instance to call them

Comment: Yeah, was a bit unclear, i mean you could make it global - then you can access the variable from everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parenthesis to the end of the statement and use the `->` operator, not the `.` operator: `player->check()`

This is because it is a pointer to an object `Player *player` and not an object itself `Player player`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, just typo. Anyway, all perfectly written, I've even tried -> and :: variants. I need some c++ way that I don't know to make it work.

Comment: Using the `::` operator would be using the method without an object

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to follow, and some of the answers reflect that. However, in my view what you are running into is actually a critically important part of your system design. There are many strategies, and many considerations, but basically it's up to you to design the paths by which objects can access the contents of other objects in your running program.

Some common techniques include
Global variables

```
extern Player *PlayerOne;
PlayerOne->item[0]=3;
```

Static variables (or collections) in the class.

```
class Player {
public:
Player* Players;
}

Player::Players[0]->item[0]=3;
```

Member variables.

```
Board.Add(new Player(Board));

Board.m_player->item[0]=3;
```

The variations are endless. You'll need to be more specific if you want specific code.

Comment: Now I thought that this is it, tried extern variable - nothing worked, even if I put extern Player *PlayerOne; in main.cpp. I cannot do PlayerOne->item from another class (c++ says was not declared in this scope =/)